# MS Charts: Different colors on label values

Tags: c#, vb.net, charts, mschart, radar-chart

Is their any possible way to get different colors on each X-Axis value of a radar chart?

Already tried custom labels, but it didn't work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are neither Properties nor [`CustomAttributes`](http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/webchart2005/CustomAttributes_All.html)  to achieve this for `AxisLabels`.

But [`CustomLabels`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.customlabel(v=vs.110).aspx) will do the job nicely.

Here is an example that adds a `CustumLabel` for each `DataPoint` in a `Series` and gives it a random color:

[image]

Set up the data:

```
Random rnd = new Random(0);
List<Color> colors = new List<Color>() { Color.Red, Color.Firebrick, Color.Gold,
    Color.DeepPink, Color.Azure, Color.IndianRed, Color.ForestGreen };

ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];

Series s = chart.Series[0];

for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{
    s.Points.AddXY(i, i+ rnd.Next(20 - i));
}
```

Now add `CustomLabels`:

```
foreach (var dp in s.Points)
{
    CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel();
    cl.FromPosition = dp.XValue;
    cl.ToPosition = dp.XValue ;
    cl.Text = dp.YValues[0]+ "$";
    cl.ForeColor = colors[rnd.Next(colors.Count)];

    ca.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(cl);
}
```

Note that for `ChartType Radar` this is rather simple; for most other types getting the `FromPosition`  and `ToPosition` is rather tricky: There you need to calculate (usually) the center between two points..

Comment: Holy cow! This was amazing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it possible to get the `DataPoint` colors on `MarkerBorderColor` too? @TaW

Comment: Sure. Make sure you set a `MarkerStyle`, though..! - `dp.MarkerBorderColor = cl.ForeColor; dp.MarkerColor = Color.MediumAquamarine; dp.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Diamond; dp.MarkerSize = 10;`  - [Example](http://imgur.com/a/TTrcl)